# Consultas SSE sobrecarregam o browser?

Tags: json, sse

Estou trabalhando num projeto web real time, que busca informação do servidor através de [SSE](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-eventsource-20110208/). Ou seja, a primeira requisição é feita ao servidor, depois disso o servidor vai enviar um JSON a cada segundo ou meio segundo para o browser.

Pensando numa situação extrema (e que é possível neste projeto) onde o browser ficará aberto por alguns meses, funcionando sem ser desligado,a minha dúvida é : o JSON enviado sobrecarrega de alguma forma o Browser? Existe algum cenário que justificasse o refresh do browser a cada X segundos por causa de algum tipo de sobrecarga?

Comment: Você deve desativar o cache na sua solicitação.

Comment: então se o cache não for desativado esses dados serão guardados em algum lugar? E se eu fizer um refresh da página a cada x segundos resolveria esse problema sem ter que desativar o cache programaticamente?

Comment: Você pode escolher o que fazer. podes desativar o cache da requisição.

Comment: refresh pode não ser a solução, ou pode ser, vai depender do que você precisa implementar.

Comment: a especificação HTTP permite que o servidor retorne um número de diretivas diferentes de Controle de cache que controlam como e por quanto tempo cada resposta pode ser armazenada em cache pelo navegador e outros caches intermediários.

Comment: Entendo. Então no cenário exemplificado onde seria possível cerca de 2764800 push de JSON por dia o único temor seria o cache?

Comment: vc está falando em kb?

Comment: Não há nenhuma limitação de tamanho inerente ao pedido geral JSON em si. Qualquer limitação seria definido pelo servidor ao analisar o pedido JSON

Comment: Não, estou falando em quantidades. Serão 2764800 JSONs enviados por dia. Cada JSON tem cerca de 400kb. A minha dúvida inicial seria se existe alguma limitação do sistema. Por exemplo, o browser ficar aberto sem refresh durante 30 dias, seriam  82944000 JSONs por mês.  Será que teria algum problema de sobrecarga em algum lugar? Cache ou memória ou CPU do cliente?

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?

Comment: Resolvi o problema. Faço um reload a cada 10min. Mas a dúvida continua.